# is it possible to trigger iPhone shortcut by address on received email?

Tags: iphone, email, shortcut, automation

How to create shortcut
based on sender address  on received email ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can do an automatisation in Shortcuts app triggered by email (from/subject/account/destination) . Check middle tab if the app.